# Using Struts tags instead of JSP expression tags(<% expression %>)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, scriptlet

I want to remove the scriptlets from this code and
I have to replace it with the Struts tags, can any one suggest me how to do it

```
     <td CLASS="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" align="left" colspan="5">
      +Name: <%=(user == null || user.getPreferredName() == null) ? "" : 
      user.getPreferredName()%>
      </td>
```

Comment: Move the code on server, use Struts tags. This will make your code compact, separated, testable, understandable.

Comment: You can use that expression in S2 `<s:property>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<logic:present/>` tag.

```
<td CLASS="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" align="left" colspan="5">
  +Name:

     <logic:present name="user"> 
         < bean:write name="user" property="preferredName"/>
     </logic:present>

    <logic:notPresent name="user"> 
        --- (no preferred name)    
    </logic:notPresent>
</td>
```

Comment: can you write the code in detail for the above code

Comment: This way you can check if logic present (not null) and then print its value. if logic not present `--- (no preferred name) ` will be printed

Answer (score 0):

Define a property with getter in your action class

```
public String getPreferredName() { return (user == null || user.getPreferredName() == null) ? "" : user.getPreferredName()   ;}
```

Change your code

```
<td CLASS="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" align="left" colspan="5">
  +Name: <s:property value="preferredName"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

this this correct format,

```
<td CLASS="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY" align="left" colspan="5">
    <s:if test="%{#user ==null } ||%{#user.preferredName ==null}">
        Name :
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        Name :<s:property value="preferredName"/>
    </s:else>
</td>
```